# How to inject bundled React using Webpack and WebpackDevMiddleWare

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, redux

I'm currently building a Universal React project using React, Redux, Express, and Webpack.

I'm having some trouble figuring out the exact build process flow for development vs production and the best way to inject my built webpack scripts in each environment.

My build process for production looks like this

- build a client.js bundle and server.js bundle from webpack. the client bundle will render my root React component and attach it to a dom element

  render(
    ,
    document.getElementById('app')
  )

the server bundle will export a function that takes in a request / response and matches my React-router routes, returning my React.renderToString content inside of a pre-defined html string that includes a path to my client.js bundle

```
function renderFullPage(renderedContent, initialState) {
  return `
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="">
    <body>
    <div id="app">${renderedContent}</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/assets/app.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
  `
}

export default function render(req, res) {
  match({ routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error.message)
    } else if (redirectLocation) {
      res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
    } else if (renderProps) {
      // const authenticated
      const store = configureStore({})
      const initialState = store.getState()
      const history = createMemoryHistory(createLocation())

      const renderedContent = renderToString(
        <Root {...renderProps } store={store} routes={routes} history={history} />
      )
      const renderedPage = renderFullPage(renderedContent, initialState)
      res.status(200).send(renderedPage)
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('Not Found')
    }
  })
}
```

- start an express server that matches all incoming routes and serves my built server.js file

  if (!isDev) {
      const builtApp = require('../../dist/assets/app.server');
  }

  export default function(app) {
      app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
          isDev ? devApp(req, res) : builtApp(req, res)
      })
  }

This process works for production, but I'm not sure how to implement it for development. For development, I start off by starting my express server. I run webpack to create a client bundle. I then apply `WebpackDevMiddleWare` which prevents an actual bundle from being outputted. Obviously when I run the above route that takes my non-built server.js file and runs it, it's going to complain since I don't have the built client file in an assets file.

Is the solution to this problem having Webpack output an html file that automatically injects the built scripts? I tried looking at `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, but I'm not sure how to make it work.

If I create an html shell and tell HtmlWebpackPlugin to ineject the scripts into that and then build an index file, how do I inject my React App Component inside?

Thanks!

Here's my setup so far if it helps: http://bit.ly/1OPR2zP